# Unable to resolve ephemeral URL when tunnel active

Tags: ubuntu, dns, tunnel

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 with GlobalProtect tunnel active.
I'm having an issue resolving ephemeral URL when tunnel is active:

```
dig 84A6AEF711729113795D839A96E112C5.gr7.us-east-1.eks.amazonaws.com

; <<>> DiG 9.16.1-Ubuntu <<>> 84A6AEF711729113795D839A96E112C5.gr7.us-east-1.eks.amazonaws.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

Here's the resolvectl settings with tunnel (gpd0) active:

```
$ sudo resolvectl domain 
Global: localdomain
Link 3 (gpd0): ~.
Link 2 (ens33): localdomain

$ sudo resolvectl dns
Global: 172.20.0.1
Link 3 (gpd0): 172.20.0.1
Link 2 (ens33): 192.168.194.2

$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 172.20.0.1
nameserver 127.0.0.53
search localdomain
$ ip route 
default via 172.20.0.8 dev gpd0 metric 10 
default via 192.168.194.2 dev ens33 proto dhcp metric 100 
4.152.214.0/24 via 192.168.194.2 dev ens33 
4.158.208.0/24 via 192.168.194.2 dev ens33 
4.175.120.0/24 via 192.168.194.2 dev ens33 
13.107.6.152/31 via 192.168.194.2 dev ens33
```

Is there some configuration that needs to go into systemd-resolved or DNS Stub Listener in order to be able to resolve ephemeral URLs?